# NSURLConnection messes up iPad memory

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection, nsrunloop

we build an iPad app that downloads a bunch of data and PDF documents from a web service (data first, documents later in the background). To do so, we use SOAP via HTTP(S) requests. It works fine and altogether, the app is running well. Problem is, if there are too many documents to download at some point the app crashes. Using Instruments I figured out that it is a memory issue, particularly NSRegularExpression and NSRunLoop. (I'm using ARC)

I could improve my code to optimize the NSRegularExpression creation. But I don't know how to improve the NSRunLoop issue.

I tried both, asynchronous and synchronous HTTP request. Using async, I had to wait for the download to finish and since sleep()/[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] aren't an option, I use

```
while ( _waitToFinish ) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Using sync request, Instruments reveals that

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```

also "waits" with help of NSRunLoop and also messes up the memory.

Is this a bug in CoreFoundation or ARC?

Is there another way to idle while waiting for the requests to finish?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

With "memory issue" I meant that the app crashes (or is killed by iOS) because it uses too much memory.

This is what Instruments shows:
[image: Instruments screenshot]
The percentage get higher the longer the app is downloading.

**Edit:**

Going further down revealed that it is NSURLConnection, that is messing up the memory. It seems that I have somehow missed setting `connection` and `receivedData` to `nil` (see [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)). This improved my memory usage again a little.

Now, there are two more big memory allocation operations:
[image]

And this is the code I think belongs to what Instruments displays:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {    
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[_receivedData mutableBytes] length:[_receivedData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.lastResponse = responseText;

    responseText = nil;
    connection = nil;
    _receivedData = nil;

    _lastResult = TRUE;
    _waitToFinish = FALSE;
}
```

Is there anything I could change to improve the code?

**Edit:** (Changed title from "NSRunLoop messes up iPad memory")

**Edit:**
I created a test app to prove that it is the NSURLConnection, that messes up the memory. Then I contacted the Apple Developer Support.

Since I am downloading a lot of PDF in an iteration with NSURLConnection, the solution was to add an `@autoreleasepool { .. }` in the iteration and another one around the `NSRunLoop`.

Thanks.

Comment: The `CFRunLoopRunInMode` probably isn't really allocating much memory itself.  It just waits for events and then calls functions that have been registered to handle those events.  You need to drill down further in that outline view to figure out what's really allocating the memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in Core Foundation or ARC.  It's a bug in your code.

Don't run the run loop yourself.  Just use `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`.  It will call your `completionHandler` block when the request is complete.  That's when you process the response.  Meanwhile, just return out of your method and let the system worry about running the run loop.

You say “it's a memory issue” with `NSRegularExpression` and `NSRunLoop`, but you don't say what the issue is, or what evidence Instruments is showing you.  If you describe the “issue” in more detail, maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just extended the question. I'll check the behaviour with your suggested code..

Comment: I tried `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`, but to get it working, I still have to loop to wait until it finishes. (Couldn't try with the queue object, since I'd have to change a lot in my app without knowing if this approach would be successful.) As you see in the screenshot above, the app still allocates a lot of memory. Can I release these?